# OpenDayLight installation error

Tags: networking, virtualbox-networking

I tried to install ODL on Ubuntu, I followed all the steps but I got these error messages (I don't know whats the password), please check the image

ERROR MSG
[image: ERROR MSG]

Comment: By posting a picture of text, you make it impossible for potential helpers on phones, or text terminals. to see your text. Rather, copy and paste the text into your Question, select it and use the `{}` formatting tool.

Comment: sorry this is my first question, I don't know how to do it

Comment: Are you logged in remotely to some other machine?

Comment: No, I did not do that